# Signal conditioning of a piezoelectric sensor

Tags: voltage, sensor, charge, piezo, data-acquisition

I am currently working on a project that involves the use of a piezoelectric sensor which is of the ceramic type and produces charge when a force is applied. I want to convert this charge to a voltage in order to evaluate the force being applied on the piezo.

[image]

I am trying to convert the charge produced by this piezo to a voltage but I keep getting constant noise on the oscilloscope.

The wave produced is a sinusoidal wave, and when a force is applied the amplitude of wave increases. The frequency if that wave is 50-60 Hz, implying that this is noise. I have attached an image of circuit used.

[image]

I need a straight line on the oscilloscope which fluctuates when a force is applied. What alterations should I make to make the circuit feasible? I am a mechanical engineering student and circuits aren't my forte, so please guide accordingly.

Comment: Datasheet for the sensor? Also, not sure a MOSFET input opamp is right approach. I'd start with discrete JFET and experiment. What does the manufacturer suggest?

Answer (score 1):

From your rather-badly drawn circuit, it appears that you have a 12 volt supply that isn't referenced to ground/0 volts. I would suggest that you take measurements relative to the mid-rail point on the 12 volt supply and call that point 0 volts. Make sure that you use that mid-point as the return wire for the piezo.